# Run application in Raspberry Pi with a web browser

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, web-browsers, web-interface

I would like to build an application Raspberry Pi for controlling a 20 Inch monitor it will display some images.

**Long story**

Each user have an account (Web based application) and he/she is logged into account and upload some images/videos into his account (Stored AWS S3 buckets).
Later he can connect his Device it includes **20 Inch monitor+Raspberry Pi** to this account.
Here the crucial part comes he can able to start some features on this monitor

some of are

1.Set up an image slideshow in the monitor.

2.Can able to stop it.

3.Cache images for some times.

ie  he/she control the monitor with a browser.
 Currently  we have Raspberry Pi 3 with RASPBIAN os  and the user web application. 
Is it possible to do with Raspberry Pi??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run a browser on your RPI and show the dynamic content on your display.

There are a few commercial packages and some [signage](https://sourceforge.net/projects/raspberrysign/) open source. The TV will have enough USB power to feed the Raspberry.

Here is a [list of open source](http://www.sixteen-nine.net/2013/12/13/10-slices-raspberry-pi-digital-signage/) and commercial signage for the Raspberry family.

Comment: Thanks but what about the performance about loading images via chrome browser  especially with 4k images??

Comment: As per RFC 2616 HTTP protocol the browser should keep images on cache, so they will be downloaded only once. Chrome or any other app will take the same time to download it. You can try your 'page' on any device and the move to the RPI.

Comment: But what about HD picture clarity